# Sums of squares and then increasing the number being square: will the sum change?

Tags: square-numbers

100 numbers are written on a board. After each number was increased by 1, the sum
of their squares did not change. Will the sum of squares change and by how much if
the numbers are increased by 1 again?
I don't know where to start since I can't find an example and that logically the sum will always change because the squares will always be non-negative.

Comment: The squares may be non-negative, but are the numbers themselves?  For example $(-4)^2+(3)^2 = (-4+1)^2+(3+1)^2$

Comment: " logically the sum will always change " The set $\{-2, 1\}$ is a set whose sum of squares is unchanged by this process.

Comment: If each of fifty $-1$s and fifty $0$s is increased by $1$, the sum of the squares won’t change. Of course, that doesn’t mean there aren’t other possibilities for the $100$ numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:   in the case of $\,3\,$ numbers, the premise is:
$$(a+1)^2+(b+1)^2+(c+1)^2 - (a^2+b^2+c^2) = 0 \;\;\iff\;\; 2(a+b+c)=-3$$

Then $\,(a+2)^2+(b+2)^2+(c+2)^2 - \big(a^2+b^2+c^2\big) = 4(a+b+c)+12=6\,$.

Comment: So the conclusion is that the sum will not change, but I am not sure how this applies to 100 numbers where 100 isn't divisible by 3.

Comment: `conclusion is that the sum will not change` On the contrary, the sum *will* change since the RHS of the last line is *not* $\,0\,$.